# Mootools Formcheck in IE9

Tags: javascript, mootools, internet-explorer-9

I think I'm not the only one with this problem. I work with http://mootools.floor.ch/en/demos/formcheck/. But it doesn't work on IE9. Does somebody know how to fix it?

Thanks a lot for your ideas!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like their example is not working because it is throwing a DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5) error in IE9. However, when I setup my own test, I am able to get the validation to work using the latest version of MooTools (1.4.5):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-more.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="formcheck/theme/classic/formcheck.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="formcheck/lang/en.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="formcheck/formcheck.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        window.addEvent('domready', function(){        
            new FormCheck('simple');    
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <br/><br/>
    <form name="simpledemo" id="simple">
        <input class="button submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <input name="simple" class="validate['required'] text-input" type="text"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also use formcheck and have posted the mootools 1.4.x compatible code here:

http://www.timwickstrom.com/client-side-code/mootools/moofloor-formcheck-for-mootools-1-4-x/

This does NOT require mootools to be in compatibility mode.